# Resources for learning Valyrian besides Duolingo course?

Tags: electronic-resources, constructed-languages, physical-resources

[Valyrian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valyrian_languages) is one of the fictional languages in Game of Thrones / A Song of Ice and Fire. Duolingo offers a [course in High Valyrian](https://en.duolingo.com/course/hv/en/Learn-High-Valyrian-Online); [David J. Peterson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_J._Peterson), who created both Dothraki and Valyrian is said to be one of the contributors.

However, are there any other resources for learning High Valyrian, either online or in print?

Answer (score 5):

The most contributed-to resources seem to be the [Valyrian Wiki](https://wiki.dothraki.org/Valyrian). There are several useful links on the Wiki: the [High Valyrian Corpus](https://wiki.dothraki.org/High_Valyrian_Corpus), the [High Valyrian Phonology](https://wiki.dothraki.org/High_Valyrian_Phonology), the [High Valyrian Vocabulary](https://wiki.dothraki.org/High_Valyrian_Vocabulary), [Valyrian Historical Linguistics](https://wiki.dothraki.org/Valyrian_Historical_Linguistics), the [Astapori Valyrian Phonology](https://wiki.dothraki.org/Astapori_Valyrian_Phonology), and the [Astapori Valyrian Vocabulary](https://wiki.dothraki.org/Astapori_Valyrian_Vocabulary) page.

The [Academy of High Valyrian](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLfvA6U-gyoBqZcwCaAEuEd5_SpdtcMRxi) is a twenty-video YouTube playlist that begins with a basic introduction to the language and goes through more advanced grammatical concepts.

The [Learn Dothraki and Valyrian](http://forum.dothraki.org/index.php?board=11.0) forum seems to be an active place to ask questions about the language as well.

Comment: The forum seems abandoned now.

Answer (score 4):

Things have changed in the years following [fi12's answer](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/a/3046/9264) (and again since I first wrote this answer).

David Peterson (DJP) uploaded his work on a [Reddit AMA](https://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/gnhs6x/keidmil_my_name_is_david_j_peterson_and_im_the/). This contains:

- [**A Wiki for all his languages**](https://wiki.languageinvention.com/index.php?title=Main_Page)<sup>1</sup> "with enough critical mass to release".
- [Almost all of his work for Game of Thrones](http://dedalvs.com/work/game-of-thrones/) - this contains a *lot* of information, including the audio snippets he created to help the actors of the show with the dialogue.
- [The dialogue of Game of Thrones](https://archiveofourown.org/users/Dedalvs/works?fandom_id=242462) "in a more digestible format".

[The Academy of High Valyrian](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLfvA6U-gyoBqZcwCaAEuEd5_SpdtcMRxi) is still the best series of videos about HV, although if you want the pronunciation (and more than the absolute basics), DJP himself made the audio (as well as the content) for the [**Duolingo course**](https://www.duolingo.com/course/hv/en/Learn-High%20Valyrian).

The forum is no longer in use, as we've instead migrated to a (more general) server on Discord named [The Languages of Ice and Fire](https://discord.gg/XxFCvUtdSe). There's also a Facebook group, [Duolingo High Valyrian Learners](https://www.facebook.com/groups/1689188698077358/).

In addition, I've also made a few resources. They're not quite as up-to-date as the Wiki, but they're not *far* behind. I will update these when time permits, but that could be a while away:

- A Dictionary, available in [word](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H35EfvdgLqFe_j-CyigofCmCXMYzs_l-/view), [pdf](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kE-yw8Naqmau3Pw8nFdcrOe81Gx2rzDg), [access database](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1q2M4Uo03pR0Pe-dAVpFrVi8NvP0GNmn5) and [csv](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1K4Zzi_ds4Zns5Fd_bzLrKpOR0Xp9hfej) formats.
- I used this to create a [Decks/Memrise course](https://decks.memrise.com/course/2048298/high-valyrian-vocab/). (there are a few others available, although they are much smaller in size)
- This was also used as the dictionary in a Discord bot called [Merlin](https://top.gg/bot/568896084999405578)<sup>2</sup>.

The links I've emboldened are the ones I view as the most important.

As a bonus, if you want to read through more detailed explanations and some details about how the language was created, DJP also made a series of [blog posts](https://dothraki.com/) over the years, where he still holds the occasional Haiku competition.

---

<sup>1 For full disclosure, I'm one of the editors</sup>

<sup>2 Created by Sorcerertech, also has a Klingon dictionary</sup>

---

There used to be a [Valyrian Wiki](https://wiki.dothraki.org/Valyrian) (aka. The Tongues of Ice and Fire Wiki). However, this has since been superceeded by DJP's own Wiki. There's also a previous Discord server, [Valyrio Udrir](https://discord.gg/U4W9xCf), but for a variety of reasons, we now mostly use the Languages of Ice and Fire server mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: It looks like the discord link doesn't work anymore. Also, as of the time of this comment, dothraki.com is down.

Comment: @CurtisShipley Ah yeah, I forgot to edit this answer, sorry - I'll edit/update it properly this evening, but essentially DJP's Wiki is now the *only* Wiki, as we've migrated from the original one

Comment: @CurtisShipley I've updated the answer to mention the new Discord Server (although I don't know what happened that the link to the previous one, which still exists, stopped working), fixed the paragraph about DJP's Wiki and moved the old Wiki to a note at the bottom

Comment: Wow, thank you so much.  Especially for the dictionaries.  Duolingo used to have a dictionary for Valyrian but no more (even back when it existed, I figured it out by modifying the url to the Spanish dictionary).